# Problem with calculating ORB descriptors on 3D model in PLY format in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mesh, 3d-reconstruction

My task is to register image from camera to point cloud of scene using C++.
My intuition here is to calculate ORB descriptors on both camera image and point cloud of scene so I can obtain point correspondences btw them and apply SolvePnP function to estimate the camera pose.
I following [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html). I load the point cloud of scene in PLY format to cv::Mat and try to calculate ORB decriptors on it. Resultant Mat object has single channel. Here is my code:

```
Mat scene_mat = loadPLYSimple("a_cloud.ply", 1);

vector<KeyPoint> kp1, kp2;
Mat des1, des2;
Ptr<Feature2D> orb = ORB::create();

orb->detectAndCompute(scene_mat, Mat(), kp2, des2);
```

When run this code I get error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor,
> file /home/vladimir/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7564
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

What is the problem with this code? Is this correct way to calculate ORB descriptors on point cloud?

Comment: unless you called cvtcolor somewhere. then i would assume the cvtcolor lies inside the detectandcompute. means the input scene_mat is not what they expected as CV_8UC3. Cout Scene_mat.channels for more debug infomation

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai Thank you for reply. cout << scene_mat.channels() gives 1 (single channel). Sadly I failed to find examples on calculating ORB descriptor on point clouds in OpenCV